# Autofilter with column formatted as date

Tags: excel, vba, date, autofilter

I am using an AutoFilter with VBA in Excel that works for regular filters, but not a column formatted as date.

I can filter it manually. If I run my code, it filters nothing but when I check the filter and then only click ok (no change being applied to the filter criteria), it filters correctly.

Here is my code:

```
ws.ListObjects(SheetName).Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1 _
        :=">" & CDate([datecell]), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:= _
        "<=" & CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth([datecell], 3))
```

It seems to be a common problem, but I have not found a solution.

When I run a recorded macro, it does not work either.

Comment: If you change your date cells format to general does it show a number?

Comment: Yes, as I said, everything works as it should. There is a problem when the filter is applied. Because the recorded macro does not work either.

Comment: Try converting to text instead. such as `CDate([datecell])` change to `Format([datecell], "dd-MMM-yy")`

Comment: Does not work either, see the answer and my comment below. It's really absurd.

Comment: That does seem a bit odd yes....  what value is `[datecell]` and `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth([datecell], 3)` if you `Debug.Print` or `msgbox` them?

Comment: [datecell] = 31.12.2012     
WorksheetFunction.EoMonth([datecell], 3) = 41364

We might be onto something.
Although it's formatted as date in the sheet.

Comment: Just changed the format for the date from Date to General and it didnt change anything.

Comment: if you `msgbox(Format([datecell],"dd-MMM-yy"))` does it give you 31-Dec-2012? Changing the cell format won't do much, as the underlying value will stay the same.

Comment: Note my comment after my answer.  The "/" in the format command gets translated to the system date separator.  To force slashes as a separator, you need to do something like:  "m""/""d""/""yyyy", or "m\/d\/yyyy"  I keep forgetting the subtle differences between VBA Format and Excel TEXT functions (and the .NumberFormat property)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Dates can be tricky with Excel VBA AutoFilter.  Some find it easier to just loop through the array to be filtered.

Sometimes I have found that one can use the numeric value of the date, especially when dealing with "dates between"

```
Criteria1:= ">" & CDbl([datecell])
Criteria2:= "<=" & CDbl(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth([datecell], 3))
```

Note that the above need to be "real dates" and not strings that look like dates. Even a single "string date" will mess things up.

Comment: Yeah, tried that as well earlier and it didnt work either. It's a mystery to me. Especially given the fact that the recorded macro does not work either.

Comment: Another option, when dealing with "dates between", is to use the Excel stored number.  See my Edit in the answer

Comment: Something else to check is that all of your dates are really dates, and not strings that happen to look like dates.  Even a single "string date" in the list will mess things up.

Comment: Edit your answer to only show the CDbl Version and I mark it as correct and vote it up.

Comment: Looking at some of your comments, and noting that your settings have the dot as a date separator, led me to do some testing.  It seems that if the dot is set as your system date separator, even if you enter Format([date],"m/d/yyyy") the system will still change the separator to a dot.  In order to get the proper US format with a slash separator, you need to use a format code of:  "m""/""d""/""yyyy"  Try this latter method and see how it works on your system.  This behavior is outlined in HELP for the VBA Format function.

Comment: I attempted this answer and at first it did not work. I also used [] to reference my range. VBA would't eat it at first. Only once i used the following construct did it work:     CDbl(ActiveSheet.Range("MyNamedRange"))

Comment: @rohrl77 Possibly you didn't have the format correct.  [..] is shorthand for Range("  ").  So you would use in your formula above:   CDbl(ActiveSheet.[MyNamedRange])

Comment: You're an angel from the sky!!

Comment: Oddly enough, .ShowAllData stops working after that

Comment: This works for me, and presumably, like the "international" date format, should not lead to any mis-reading by Excel (all  dates are just a number in Excel after all)

Answer (score 13):

`Autofilter()` works with 'universal' format `yyyy-mm-dd`, i.e.:

```
Criteria1:= ">" & Format([MY_DATE],"yyyy-mm-dd")
Criteria2:= "<=" & Format([MY_DATE],"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

It's better because Excel can't 'understand' it wrong . If you use `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` Excel can fit 02/jan as 01/feb.

see: 
http://www.oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Ch22/ProgRefCh22.htm

> The Rules for Working with Excel ([International Issue](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Ch22/ProgRefCh22.htm))
>
> 2. When you have to convert numbers and dates to strings for passing to Excel (such as in criteria for AutoFilter or .Formula strings), always explicitly convert the data to a US-formatted string, using Trim(Str(MyNumber)), or the sNumToUS() function shown earlier, for all number and date types. Excel will then use it correctly and convert it to the local number/date formats.

---

**Edit:**

We can create an universal Function using `Application.International` like:

```
Sub MySub()
    Select Case application.International(xlDateOrder)
        Case Is = 0
            dtFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Case Is = 1
            dtFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Case Is = 2
            dtFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
        Case Else
            dtFormat = "Error"
    End Select

    Debug.Print (dtFormat)

    ...
    Criteria1:= ">" & Format([MY_DATE],dtFormat)
    Criteria2:= "<=" & Format([MY_DATE],dtFormat)
    ...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to convert the format to the american format, like:

```
">" & Format([datecell], "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

VBA does not understand another format.

Answer (score 1):

Karlos Henrique,
Thanks for suggesting Format([datecell], "mm/dd/yyyy").
It works in my file.
My previous code is :

```
Range("A1:D" & Trim(Str(LstRec))).AutoFilter Field:=2, _
  Criteria1:=">=" & StrtDt, _
  Operator:=xlAnd, _
  Criteria2:="<=" & EndDt
```

My modified code is :

```
Range("A1:D" & Trim(Str(LstRec))).AutoFilter Field:=2, _
  Criteria1:=">=" & Format(StrtDt, "mm/dd/yyyy"), _
  Operator:=xlAnd, _
  Criteria2:="<=" & Format(EndDt, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax works for me:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

Hint obtained through a macro registration

Answer (score 0):

Match your "dd-mm-yyy" to the format of the column, so if you have "16-Aug-16" as your source data formatting then make the filter as "dd-mmm-yy"

Comment: This worked for me... my column was formatted as dd-mmmm-yyyy and that threw everything out.  Changing the criteria fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set up correctly the format of the target column. If its formatted as "custom", even if it looks like a date, it won't work.

You are asking VBA to filter based on a date, therefore the format of the columns has to be a date too.

Answer (score 0):

SO this worked for me pretty clean

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$35727").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & Range("G1"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("H1")
```

You can try this as well

Expected output will start date in my G1 cell and end date will be H1 cell.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, while filtering column with date. When I changed system date format to 01/01/2020, it converted my date to 1/1/2020 in Criteria field. 
My solution was to convert arguments to str during setting to function.

Answer (score -1):

here's the occam's razor solution... try putting this in Autoopen for the spreadsheet or if you need to, modify it for the sheet that you wish to affect. it will cause the drop down filters for the date headers to appear as individual dates and not as a date hierarchy.

`ActiveWindow.AutoFilterDateGrouping = False`