# Taking over the date correctly to select the searching criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I try through a combobox on a form (Periode) to let people select 2 dates to search through the data within a certain period. The selected date is used as a selection criteria to search within the data. I do it through this code:

```
Private Sub Datumok_Click()
Dim AA1 As String
Dim AA2 As String
Dim AA3 As String
Dim AA4 As String
Dim AA5 As String
Dim AA6 As String
Dim LastRow As Single

AA1 = Me.dag1.Value
AA2 = Me.maand1.Value
AA3 = Me.jaar1.Value
AA4 = Me.dag2.Value
AA5 = Me.maand2.Value
AA6 = Me.jaar2.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Feuil2").Select
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Start").Range("F7") = AA2 & "-" & AA1 & "-" & AA3
Sheets("Start").Range("G7") = AA5 & "-" & AA4 & "-" & AA6
Sheets("Start").Range("F8") = AA1 & "-" & AA2 & "-" & AA3
Sheets("Start").Range("G8") = AA4 & "-" & AA5 & "-" & AA6
Unload Periode
Sheets("Feuil2").Select
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 10)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(LastRow, 3)).AutoFilter Field:=3,                     ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(LastRow, 3)).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheets("Start").Range("F8"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Sheets("Start").Range("G8")
Cells(1, 1).Select
Sheets("Start").Select
Cells(8, 5).Value = "Ok"

'Wel blad updaten
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A bit nasty code maybe. The selection is put to a cell and those 2 cells are used as selection criteria.
Sometimes the vba or Excel doesn't take over the date, but when I do it by hand in the filter it works. Does anybody knows how to improve the code, that it always works?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You didn't even ask a question at all in this post!

Comment: Why do you use 2 dates in 2 different formats in F7, G7, F8 and G8?

Comment: Good question. It is the difference for the English date (for the filter) and the (Dutch) date to show for the user.

Comment: The data is a mix of numbers and text. The first column is a title of the rows (with no data for the date). The dates of the data is put into row 3. I am not so used to filter it like that. But it should take the whole part (in my view) like that.

Comment: The rows are divided like this:  [2] [06] [38726] (time in Excel format) [09] [bla] [0,61] [101,2] [74,3] [ok] [ok] [1:05] [88] [21] ([] is a column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first step is eliminate all the `.Select` statements and to work directly with the objects you need.

The next step is to remove the 3 (I think) `.AutoFitler` statements you have in your code and only use one. I have refactored your code a bit (and put some comments so I can show my interpretations of your code).

```
Private Sub Datumok_Click()

Dim AA1 As String
Dim AA2 As String
Dim AA3 As String
Dim AA4 As String
Dim AA5 As String
Dim AA6 As String
Dim sSE As String
Dim sEE As String
Dim LastRow As Single

'start date
AA1 = Me.dag1.Value 'day
AA2 = Me.maand1.Value 'month
AA3 = Me.jaar1.Value 'year

'end date
AA4 = Me.dag2.Value 'day
AA5 = Me.maand2.Value 'month
AA6 = Me.jaar2.Value 'year

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Start")
    .Range("F7") = AA2 & "-" & AA1 & "-" & AA3
    .Range("G7") = AA5 & "-" & AA4 & "-" & AA6
    .Range("F8") = AA1 & "-" & AA2 & "-" & AA3
    sSE = .Range("F8").Value2
    .Range("G8") = AA4 & "-" & AA5 & "-" & AA6
    sEE = .Range("G8").Value2
End With

Unload Periode

With Sheets("Feuil2")

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    'filters columns A(1) through J(10) ... adjust based on your needs
    .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 10)).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & sSE, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & sEE

End With

With Sheets("Start")
    .Select
    .Cells(8, 5).Value = "Ok"
End With

'Wel blad updaten
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason why you do use the with / end with part? For the rest you are right. The only strange thing is that sSE is a number (42005) and sEE is a date (30/11/2015) and I can't figure out why (both cells are in date format on the Excelsheet as far as I know).

Comment: `With blocks` allow for faster processing (and easier code-reading IMO). The number `42005` is simply the date in Excel's date value format. The date `30/11/2015` is not recognized in US dates, so depending on your regional settings, it may not be recognizing it as an actual date (this it is just giving you the string).

Comment: sSE = CDate(.Range("F8").Value2)
    sEE = CDate(.Range("G8").Value2)
    Corrects the date part, but your filter throws an '1004' error.

Comment: @Helfenstein - sorry, I fixed the filter so it will include columns A:J ... adjust as needed. Also assumes row 1 is column headers

Comment: I went back to my code and part of your code, but apparently with CDate it still manage to get two different ways of doing the dates as selection criteria (one like 1-01-2015 and one like 30/11/2015).

Comment: @Helfenstein - just adjust the code to make sure you 2nd English (US)date is in a format that is valid for a English (US) date, so the autofilter can recognize it.

Comment: I found the problem, but now to find the solution ... When the date value is not found (not in the data) it can't set the right values as criteria, but doing it manually it works.

Comment: Finally ... you are right [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/excel-vba-autofilter-not-working-with-date-column) & Format(sEE, "mm/dd/yyyy") did the trick to let the auto-filter understand it.