# Filtering Data for 2 months prior

Tags: excel, vba

I'm able to filter data for the previous month using the below code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CV$39198").AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:= _
        xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to filter out dates for the month before last (for example: it's June Now and I want to filter April dates) Then next month, July, I want it to filter May dates without having to update coding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/excel-vba-autofilter-not-working-with-date-column