# Visual basic excel: filter to show dates earlier than today

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Visual Basic within Excel so that I can use a macro linked to a button to filter a table showing all rows with dates today or earlier than today. When I use the following code, no rows are displayed:

```
Sub showoverdue_Click()
Range("A7:L500").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A7:L500").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & Date
End Sub
```

When I change the operator to =, today's date is correctly filtered for but I can't get "<" or "<=" to work correctly.

My date data is formatted using UK formatting (dd/mm/yyyy)- I'm not sure if this is having an effect.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/excel-vba-autofilter-not-working-with-date-column

Comment: Thanks- that thread helped- now working!

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

Running:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim s As String
    s = "<" & CStr(Date)
    With Columns("A:A")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=s
    End With
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem as before with this but the thread recommended above helped. Thanks