# VBA Autofilter exclude Date criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter dates by excluding input date criteria but not succeed, my code selecting all the dates in the filter. Please help me with the code, I want to exclude the input date and select remaining dates in the filter column. below is my code.

[image]

```
Sub Date_Filter()

Dim fdate As String


fdate = InputBox("Enter report From date in (Ex: DD/MM/yyy)format Ex:23/Oct/2019", Format(Now(), "dd/mmm/yyyy"))


Range("A1:G" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>" & fdate, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Selection.Copy
Sheets("Observation").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: To autofilter dates can be tricky.  See [Excel VBA Autofilter not working with Date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/excel-vba-autofilter-not-working-with-date-column). Basically you need to work with "real dates" and use the numeric equivalent when setting the criteria.

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfeld,

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfeld, thanks for the reply. I have referred the post mentioned by you but no luck, could you please help me with the code to exclude 18/Nov/2019 and select remaining dates in autofilter.

Comment: Are the dates in your table "real dates"? Or are they text strings? Edit your post to show how you tried to apply the principles shown in the linked post.