# Autofilter messing up date format?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use autofilter to filter a date column within a date range. I wrote my code and noticed it wasn't working so I dumbed it down and tried recording a macro. It seems that not even recording a macro is working because it's messing up the date formats. I have Excel in Spanish and I'm trying to use dd/mm/yyyy date format. I decided to record a macro by filtering from 10/01/2020 to 20/01/2020 and it gives me the following code:

```
Selection.AutoFilter

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$95").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
    ">=10/01/2020", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=20/01/2020"
```

When I did it manually as I was recording the macro, it filtered 3 results, but when I try running the macro again, it messes up the date format. If I check the filter applied it says "is after or equal to: 01/10/2020" and "is before or equal to: 20/01/2020". Any idea why it's changing the format of just one date when I run the code and how to fix it?

Thank you

I've also tried using the Format function

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$95").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & Format("10/01/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Format("20/1/2020", "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

And it still changes "10/01/2020" to "01/10/2020" when filtering

Comment: Take a look at [Auto Filter with Column formatted as date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/autofilter-with-column-formatted-as-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel likes to assume formatting. I believe it is based on your language settings. You can reformat using `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$95").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`

```
Selection.AutoFilter

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$95").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
    ">=10/01/2020", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=20/01/2020"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$95").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I tried that and it changes the format of the column but when filtering it still shows "is after or equal to: 01/10/2020" and "is before or equal to: 20/01/2020" as the filter applied :/

Comment: Perhaps you can change the date to the format it is defaulting to then completing the criteria?

Comment: That actually helped me solve it! I changed the format to mm/dd/yyyy, filtered and then changed it back. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)