# How do plot a line graph showing arrival time on dates within a selected period using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use Excel VBA to develop a punctuality assessment app. I successfully created a form that collects office arrival times on each day. The form post the date and time in columns B and C respectively. Now I want to generate a line graph to show arrival times for a user selected period such that the time would be plotted along the vertical axis (y-axis) while the dates of the selected period on the horizontal axis (x-axis).

The VBA codes for the data collection works fine however the ones for the graph doesn't. The specific problems are:

1. It does not filter the data based on the selected period.
2. The dates of the selected period does not show on the x-axis. Instead, numerals 1, 2, 3, ..., are shown along the x-axis.

This is what I tried:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name

    ' Find the last row in column B
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' OK button click event
    ' Add your code to process the collected data here

    ' Get the data from the controls
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date

    ' Validate and get start date
    If DTPickerStartDate.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a valid start date.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        startDate = DTPickerStartDate.Value
    End If

    ' Validate and get end date
    If DTPickerEndDate.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a valid end date.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        endDate = DTPickerEndDate.Value
    End If

    ' Check if the worksheet is initialized
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet not initialized. Run the Initialize subroutine first.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Filter data based on the selected period
    Dim filteredDataRange As Range
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' Clear any existing filters
    ws.Range("B2:C" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endDate
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set filteredDataRange = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(0, 1) ' .Resize(ws.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Create a line graph based on the filtered data
    If Not filteredDataRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Create or update the graph
        Dim chartObj As ChartObject
        If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
            ' Update existing chart
            Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects(1)
            chartObj.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=filteredDataRange.Offset(0, 0).Resize(filteredDataRange.Rows.Count, 1) ' Include both date and arrival time
        Else
            ' Create new chart
            Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=400, Top:=20, Height:=225)
            chartObj.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=filteredDataRange.Offset(0, 0).Resize(filteredDataRange.Rows.Count, 1) ' Include both date and arrival time
            chartObj.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
        End If

        ' Customize chart properties as needed
        chartObj.Chart.HasTitle = True
        chartObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Punctuality Trend for Period " & Format(startDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " to " & Format(endDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        chartObj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        chartObj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Date"
        chartObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        chartObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Punctuality Time"
    Else
        MsgBox "No data found for the specified period.", vbExclamation
    End If

    ' Turn off the AutoFilter
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ' Cancel button
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

A Screenshot of the output I got

[image: 1]

Comment: [Autofilter with column formatted as date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/autofilter-with-column-formatted-as-date)